# Title and Meta Description built using AngularJS doesn't work in Social Media

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, slimerjs

Whenever I shared website link in facebook, twitter or anywhere, I get the following:

```
{{title}}
{{metadescription}}
```

When I inspect element using Chrome, I can see the Title and Meta Description correctly.

Could someone shed some light and how to fix it?

Do I have to install PhontomJS/SlimerJS etc? I heard PhantomJS takes a lot of server memory/process.

Comment: These social media sites don't actually parse javascript. See this post for a possible solution http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app in fact this post shows exactly what yours is doing regarding meta tags https://prerender.io/ was also built to solve this problem

Comment: prerender.io is too expensive. I would prefer a free self hosted solution. Looking at PhantomJS and other alternatives.

Comment: That first link I posted will probably help you out then if your server is apache

Comment: I'm using Python on django with angularJS running nginx. Thanks though.